# Google Apps is now G Suite - should the tag be changed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Google Apps is now G Suite - should the [google-apps tag](https://serverfault.com/tags/google-apps/info) be changed to g-suite? It currently has 433 questions.

Comment: I would ask, is it's a new version ? as often a rebranding come with feature change and UI change. As I would tend to not change it if it mean newer UI's stuff, to differentiate historical question and newer question on the main site.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I'm not clear that the adding of new features will be any different from new features added since the release of the service, yet many old features will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good idea, the tag has been merged.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it should be changed but a new tag [g-suite](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/g-suite) should be created and  [google-apps](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-apps) should be synonymed to it. To that end I have created [g-suite](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/g-suite) but it will require a moderator to create the synonym.